# After convert JSON array to NSDictionary, what should I do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I need to parse a JSON array in the following format:

```
[
 {
  name: "10-701 machine learning",
  _id: "52537480b97d2d9117000001",
  __v: 0,
  ctime: "2013-10-08T02:57:04.977Z"
 },
 {
  name: "15-213 computer systems",
  _id: "525616b7807f01fa17000001",
  __v: 0,
  ctime: "2013-10-10T02:53:43.776Z"
 }
]
```

So after getting the NSData, I transfer it to a NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

But viewing from the console, I think the dictionary is actually like this:

```
(
        {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 52537480b97d2d9117000001;
        ctime = "2013-10-08T02:57:04.977Z";
        name = "10-701 machine learning";
    },
        {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 525616b7807f01fa17000001;
        ctime = "2013-10-10T02:53:43.776Z";
        name = "15-213 computer systems";
    }
)
```

What do those parenthesis in the outside mean? How should I further transfer this NSDictionary to an NSArray or an NSMutableArray of some Course objects (what I defined myself, try to represent each element of the JSON array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code,

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then you can retrieve the values by following code,

```
NSString *v = [dict objectForKey:@"__v"];
NSString *id = [dict objectForKey:@"_id"];
NSString *ctime = [dict objectForKey:@"ctime"];
NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Why use a loop for the keys?

Answer (score 0):

The parenthesis are just the result of NSDictionary output format not being exactly the same thing as how JSON is formatted. Your code still successfully converted the JSON into a NSDictionary object.

I think what you really want, though, is an array of dictionaries. Something like this:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSDictionary *firstObject = [json objectAtIndex:0];
```

After this, `firstObject` would contain:

```
{
    "__v" = 0;
    "_id" = 52537480b97d2d9117000001;
    "ctime" = "2013-10-08T02:57:04.977Z";
    "name" = "10-701 machine learning";
}
```

And you can retrieve the information with `objectForKey:`

```
NSString *time = [firstObject objectForKey:@"ctime"];
// time = "2013-10-08T02:57:04.977Z"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The parens means it's an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Why use `valueForKey:`? Just use `objectForKey:` or modern syntax: `NSString *time = firstObject[@"ctime"];`.

Comment: `valueForKey` Just ends up calling `objectForKey` anyway. Minor syntactical differences, whatever works best for you.

Comment: It's not a minor syntactical difference. `objectForKey:` and `valueForKey:` do different things and have different uses. If you simply want a direct value for a key from a dictionary, use `objectForKey:`. If you need the extra overhead and features of KVC, use `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go ahead and change it.